# C# Универсальный метод с универсальным возвращаемым типом

Tags: c#, generics, интерфейс

Пытаюсь понять как работают Generic методы, типы и прочее
имеется вот такой код

```
public static ReadType MyMethod<ReadType>(int MyValue1, int MyValue2) 
{
    byte[] bytes = new[8]{ MyValue1, MyValue2};
    return (ReadType)Convert.ChangeType(bytes, typeof(ReadType));
}
```

Использовать я его пытаюсь так

```
label1.Text = MyMethod<int>(100, 100).ToString();
```

Но вылетает исключение

```
Объект должен реализовывать интерфейс IConvertible.
```

Я знаю что можно использовать возвращаемый тип

```
dynamic
```

Но мне хочется всё же понять, как решить эту проблему, пытался делать вот так

```
ReadType MyMethod<ReadType>(int MyValue1, int MyValue2) where ReadType : IConvertible
```

Никаких плодов это не принесло, я MSDN перешерстил, подобные вопросы искал, но не могу решить свою проблему, как же всё таки реализовать этот интерфейс и решить эту проблему?

Очень надеюсь на подробное описание и решение данной проблемы.

Comment: замените MyMethod<ReadType> - тут задается строгая привязка к типу, если нужно использовать generic, замените на MyMethod<T>(T property)

Comment: ReadType в данном случае и есть T - просто названо не шаблонно.

Comment: `int a = (int)Convert.ChangeType(bytes, typeof(int));` - и посмотрите, какой будет результат

Comment: Начнем с того, что приведенный вами код метода вообще не компилируется. Вы нас где-то обманываете.

Answer (score 6):

Смотрим, что говорится на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) о `Convert.ChangeType`:

```
public static object ChangeType
(  
    object value,  
    Type conversionType  
)
```

> `value`
>       Type: `System.Object`
>
> ```
> Объект, реализующий интерфейс IConvertible.
> ```

Смотрим на описание класса `Array`:

```
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, ICollection, 
    IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
```

Реализует массив интерфейс `IConvertible`? Нет, не реализует. Следовательно, его нельзя использовать в качестве первого параметра.
То есть ошибка выдается не о том типе, в который Вы пытаетесь конвертировать данные, а об исходном `byte[]`.

Да и как вообще Вы представляете преобразование 8 байт (64 бита) в Int32 (32 бита)? В каком порядке эти байты должны обрабатываться? Что с ними должно происходить при преобразовании? Всё это знаете Вы - но никак не разработчики языка. Это не очевидное преобразование.

Используйте какую-то другую логику преобразования вместо `Convert.ChangeType`.

Comment: Мой метод, просто как пример, я могу написать кучу подобных примеров, я пытаюсь найти решение любое, кроме обработки типов данных в ручную, путём условий, а так же не использовать dynamic.
Например byte[] bytes = new byte[4]{...}
32 == 32 бита, что в таком случае, и какую логику можете подсказать по этому поводу?

Comment: "Например byte[] bytes = new byte[4]{...} 32 == 32 бита, что в таком случае, и какую логику можете подсказать по этому поводу?" - а что Вы хотите получить-то? Но в любом случае, эта логика не будет реализована Через Convert.ChangeType. Потому что этот метод нельзя применить к массиву. И никакой dynamic тут не поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Касательно массива байтов -- почему бы не сделать вот так?

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value1)
                           .Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(value2))
                           .ToArray();
```